# how to fix the csv file formate while downloading a field in csv format from javascript from aura component

Tags: apex, javascript, aura

I have an aura component to export the sobject details into csv file. I have a field EAN10 of type test on sobject which holds a number. when i download the file the value in EAN10 field is coming in exponential format but i should get them in number format. Could i achieve it.
JS controller

```
downloadCsv : function(component,event,helper){
    var stockData = component.get("v.ListOfLineItems");
    console.log('ListOfLineItems==>'+stockData);
    var csv = helper.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(component,stockData);   
    if (csv == null){
        return;
    }     
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_self'; // 
    hiddenElement.download = 'ProductLineItemsData.csv';  
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); 
    hiddenElement.click(); 
},
```

aura component UI : 
[image]

downloaded csv file 
[image]

it should be as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try checking if the issue is present even when google sheets or another spreadsheet software?

As mentioned in https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i9brAAAit could be excel issue can you try checking the above and also can you try if you format the column in Excel to text, you'll see the actual number instead as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Hi I can able to format the columns once i have downloaded the sheet from salesforce, but we need to do it from code it self because we are going to provide this sheet as a template to users to upload the records as well where they need to enter the EAN number in the correct format, as we can not expect users to take care of this, i have to provide them the CSV in correct format so that upload should not fail.

Comment: So did you get a chamce to test it in google sheets?

Comment: Hi Anutej - as far as i know about google sheets, those can be used as shared sheets. How i can impose them in my case. Here we are not placing this template any where. When ever user want to do upload they will download it from salesforce and add the required details and upload them back.

Comment: I searched for a way to format before download but unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution that could be done instead there are various solutions given in https://superuser.com/questions/861964/how-do-i-stop-excel-from-converting-value-0503e000-to-5-03e02-automatically. One of them is to have the values between "" or try using another tool to view csv files.